# 3CX app connecting issue in LAN and wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, ethernet, connection, troubleshooting

As part of my work i need to use 3CX calling app in my company laptop. But by using wifi and not able to connect. Whole I am using LAN or even mobile hotspot, I am able to connect the application.
Provide a solution for this.. How can I resolve the issue. Is any issue with modem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Company required software on a company laptop? You need to talk to your IT staff regarding this issue. They will be aware of the configurations and requirements and can advise on what may need to be adjusted with your modem or network or device in order to get this working.